# Out of 4 argument only 3 argument Data is inserted in Sqlite3 but not one using tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I have created two files one fronted.py and another backed.py. 
As I was creating one small desktop executable app. I am not able to fetch the Title while inserting the
data and viewing in the textbox.

When I insert the data by UI tkinter app and while displaying all other data shows in the text box except the title. I really did all I could do .. but couldn't find the solution. 
please anyone will help me in this.

Here is my backend.py code

```
import sqlite3

def connect():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, aurther TEXT, year INTEGER, isbn INTEGER)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def insert(title,aurther,year,isbn):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)",(title,aurther,year,isbn))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def view():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM book")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows


def search(title="",aurther="",year="",isbn=""):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE title=? OR aurther=? OR year=? OR isbn=?", (title,aurther, year, isbn))
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows


def delete(id):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM book WHERE id=?",(id,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def update(id,title,aurther,year,isbn):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE book SET title=?,aurther=?,year=?,isbn=? WHERE id=?",(title,aurther,year,isbn,id,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


connect()
print(view())
```

Frontend.py code goes here

```
from tkinter import *
import backend


def view_command():
    list1.delete(0,END)
    for row in backend.view():
        list1.insert(END,row)

def search_command():
    list1.delete(0,END)
    for row in backend.search(title_text.get(),aurther_text.get(),year_text.get(),isbn_text.get()):
        list1.insert(END,row)

def add_command():
    backend.insert(title_text.get(),aurther_text.get(),year_text.get(),isbn_text.get())
    list1.delete(0,END)
    list1.insert(END,(title_text.get(),aurther_text.get(),year_text.get(),isbn_text.get()))


window=Tk()

l1=Label(window, text="Title")
l1.grid(row=0,column=0)

l2=Label(window, text="Aurther")
l2.grid(row=0,column=2)

l3=Label(window, text="Year")
l3.grid(row=1,column=0)

l4=Label(window, text="ISBN")
l4.grid(row=1,column=2)

title_text=StringVar()
e1=Entry(window, textvariable="title_text")
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)

aurther_text=StringVar()
e2=Entry(window, textvariable=aurther_text)
e2.grid(row=0,column=3)

year_text=StringVar()
e3=Entry(window, textvariable=year_text)
e3.grid(row=1,column=1)

isbn_text=StringVar()
e4=Entry(window, textvariable=isbn_text)
e4.grid(row=1,column=3)

list1=Listbox(window, height=9, width=40)
list1.grid(row=2, column=0,rowspan=7,columnspan=3)

sb1=Scrollbar(window)
sb1.grid(row=2,column=2,rowspan=6)

list1.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
sb1.configure(command=list1.yview)

b1=Button(window,text="View All", width=12,command=view_command)
b1.grid(row=2, column=3)

b2=Button(window,text="Search Entry", width=12, command=search_command)
b2.grid(row=3, column=3)

b3=Button(window,text="Add Entry", width=12, command=add_command)
b3.grid(row=4, column=3)

b4=Button(window,text="Update Selected", width=12)
b4.grid(row=5, column=3)

b5=Button(window,text="Delete Selected", width=12)
b5.grid(row=6, column=3)

b6=Button(window,text="Close", width=12)
b6.grid(row=7, column=3)



window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used a string `"title_text"` as `textvariable` instead of the actual `title_text` `StringVar`:

```
title_text=StringVar()
e1=Entry(window, textvariable="title_text")
```

Use the actual `title_text`:

```
e1=Entry(window, textvariable=title_text)
```